# How to join add Manytomany to an objects after upload file in django 1.1

Tags: django, file-upload, many-to-many

here my  model :

```
class ClientWash (models.Model) :
    nom = models.CharField('Nom du client',max_length=200)
    fichier = models.ManyToManyField('ClientWashFichier',null=True, blank=True)
    date_crea = models.DateField(('Date de creation'), auto_now_add=True)
    date_modif = models.DateField(('Date de modification'), auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.nom)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['nom']

class ClientWashFichier (models.Model) :
    fichier = models.FileField ('fichier',upload_to='washtest')
    date_crea = models.DateField(('Date de creation'), auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %(self.fichier)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_crea']
```

I upload with no problem, and i Succed using my file.. but i don't find how to add my file to my clientwash model...

i try :

```
fichier = ClientWashFichier.objects.get(fichier=request.FILES)
client.fichier.add(fichier)
```

but doesn't works.. little help is welcome

thx

laurent

Comment: What error do you get? What happens or doesn't happen? As an aside; You should accept some of the answers to your previous questions.

Comment: i cant' add my upload file to my model clientwash

Comment: Have you saved the model after `client.fichier.add(fichier)`?

Comment: yes... but i think this line is not good : fichier = ClientWashFichier.objects.get(fichier=request.FILES) error CLientWashFichier matching query does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the contents of request.FILES before you can assign them to a field. To do that isn't so bad, just let your default storage do the work:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage 
# Where 'file' is the id of your file input, and path is where it should be saved
path = '/'
saved_file = default_storage.save(path, request.FILES['file'])
f = ClientWashFichier()
f.fichier = saved_file
f.save()
client.fichier.add(f)
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Ok thx, but first my file is already store with my form validation. Need i stored again ? thx